# How to plot a graph based on a specific value of a feature in hue seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataset as below

| Date | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21-08-2022 | ... | ... |
| 22-08-2022 | ... | ... |

There are many dates in my csv file. I want to plot x and y based on hue=Date. Since there are many dates, the plot which I am getting from seaborn is too many lineplots in one single plot due to which I am not able to analyse the result

[image]

```
ax =sns.lineplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue=df['DATE'] )
```

I want to split the plot by plotting only 2 dates at a time. Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

How to mention the specific date (e.g: 21-08-2022) under hue=date

Comment: likely helpful [link](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1693)

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? How about slicing rows  `data[0:2]`, `data[2:4]`, etc. and plot every slice separatelly. And you can use `for`-loop with `data[i:i+2]` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice your data using the requested date:

```
ax =sns.lineplot(data=df[df['DATE'] == '22-08-21'], x="x", y="y", hue=df['DATE'] )
```